# insert data through date&time fom one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following query,

```
INSERT INTO Table[B] SELECT * FROM Table[A] WHERE (date between '2006-03-01 00:00:00' and '2006-05-31 23:59:59' and hour(date) between 5pm and 9am );
```

but it is not working .

actually i want to insert values form A to B having time 05pm to 09am

any solution please .

Comment: Could you please add little more example as it is not clear, thanks.

Comment: i have a table. which has many records also having date&time column . i created a table[B] like table[A]  . actually i want to copy those records between time 5:00pm and 9:00am   from table[A] to [B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (col1, col2, . . .)
    SELECT col1, col2, . . .
    FROM TableA
    WHERE date >= '2006-03-01' AND date < '2006-06-01' AND
          (hour(date) < 9 OR hour(date) > 17);
```

Notes:

- Explicitly list the columns when doing `insert`.
- Explicitly list the columns where the values are from.
- The date comparisons are simplified by using `>=` and `<`.

Comment: Thank's for the kindnes sir , <3